# Добавление новой записи в связанные таблицы

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio, bindingsource

Подскажите как добавить новую запись в связанные таблицы. Делаю так 
`

```
 // добавить новую запись в базу users
  usersBindingSource.AddNew();
  ....
  usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
  usersTableAdapter.Update(users_DataSet1.Users);
 // получить id нового user
 int id = (int)((DataRowView)usersBindingSource.Current).Row["UsedID"];
// создать запись Contact для нового User
  contactBindingSource.AddNew();
  ....
  contactBindingSource.EndEdit();
  contactTableAdapter.Update(users_DataSet1.Contact);
```

`

В итоге вместо id получаю значение -1. Если обновить таблицу users

```
this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.users_DataSet1.Users);
```

то слетает текущая позиция. Думаю, что должен быть более простой способ.

Comment: Очевидно, id генерируется в БД. Значит, после Update нужно сделать Select, чтобы получить этот сгенерированный id.

Comment: Да, Select делается с помощью Fill. Текущую позицию нужно запоминать в переменной и потом вручную задавать.

Comment: И потом искать запись и получать её id? После Fill меняется и Position и Current

Comment: Запоминать "текущую позицию" (position). Но после Fill меняется и Position и Current и Position уже не указывает на новую запись, а как правило на первую в списке.

Comment: Можно же просто сделать запрос select. Без помощи TableAdapter.